# Unable to receive data in a Web API HttpPost method from React axios post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My Web API Post method is working fine with Swagger, but when I send a post request from my React App with axios, the data [FromBody] is null.
Here is the Web API method.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/employee/addMany")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] dynamic data)  //my axios request hit this method but data is always null. I have tried passing without stringifying
  {
   Employee[] employees=JObject.Parse(data);
   //doing some stuff with employees
   return Ok();
  }
```

And here is the Axios post request code

```
export function addEmployees(employees:Employee[]) {
  return axios.post(`api/employee/addMany`, { employees });
}
```

And here is the request interceptor, performing Model Keys Pascalization and Stringifying data.

```
const pascalizeKeys = (obj:any):any => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map(v => pascalizeKeys(v));
  } else if (obj !== null && obj.constructor === Object) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
      (result, key) => ({
        ...result,
        [String(upperFirst(key))]: pascalizeKeys(obj[key]),
      }),
      {},
    );
  }
  return obj;
};

export function applyInterceptors(Axios:typeof axios){
  Axios.interceptors.request.use((request)=>{
    if(request.data){
      request.data = JSON.stringify(pascalizeKeys(request.data));
      return request;
    }
    return request;
  }
  )
}
```

Comment: I've had quite a few issues with axios and post recently and it is a notorious issue, see here https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1195 (also contains some suggestions as to what you could try). Can you try first by setting the headers to  'content-type': 'application/json' then by trying to attach to either the data or the params field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to try to get axios post working:

1. Set the headers

```
headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
     }
```

2. Try attaching your json to either the `data` or `params` field of the request
3. If you still can't manage to get your data, send it as a new `formData` in the data field instead

```
let formData = new FormData()

formdata.append('name', yourJson)

await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/your/url',
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
})
```

and you should get it with your request now

Comment: enjoy buddy :)  you are 300+